# How to get at openapi server values

Tags: go, yaml, openapi, viper-go

I have the following `yaml` `openapi 3` config' for my servers:

```
servers:
  - url: "localhost"
    description: "localhost development server"
    variables:
        port:
            default: ":10000"
```

Getting at those values via `viper` is trivial without that pesky dash, but I'm struggling with it (which is necessary to make the `yaml` `openapi 3` compliant.

Doing this:

```
servers := viper.Get("servers")
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(servers))
fmt.Println(servers)
```

Tells me this:

```
[]interface {}
[map[description:localhost development server url:localhost variables:map[port:map[default::10000]]]]
```

But my n00bie `golang` abilities are lacking the ninja skillz to retrieve that `:10000` value for `port`.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated to the question - it should be `url: "localhost{port}"`, i.e. the variable needs to be actually included in the `url`.

Comment: @Helen - ah yes, I think I removed that yesterday, as I was having enough problems getting at the values without that added complication! If I can get everything above working, I'll add it back, pronto :)

Comment: Just an fyi - I have (currently) given up trying to support `openapi 3` and have removed dashes from the `yaml`. It means I've had to introduce nasty hacks regarding multiple parameters, but hey, I have something that works for the proof of concept I'm working on. In other words, I'll revisit this later ;)

Answer (score 0):

`servers` is an array. Assuming Viper cannot deal with arrays, you first have to index `servers` to get the object in it:

```
server:=servers[0]
```

Once you have the server, assuming it is a `map[string]interface{}`, you can descend down:

```
if v, ok:=server["variables"]; ok {
   if varMap, ok:=v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
      if p, ok:=varMap["port"]; ok {
        if port, ok:=p.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
           if d, ok:=port["default"]; ok {
               defaultValue=fmt.Sprint(d)
           } 
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like that already, but it falls down at the first hurdle: `server:=servers[0]`, giving the error `Invalid operation: servers[0] (type interface {} does not support indexing)`